# How do I create a count measure based on filter selections?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to create a `count` measure filtered by 30, 60 and 90 days.

If a directorate, such as `NSD` is selected, I must get a count for how many dates are in each column heading such as Design In Review.

The dates in the table are based off of measure calculations as well. I'm unsure whether that makes a real difference.

[image]

Comment: Does `CALCULATE ( )` help?

Comment: No I need help creating a measure for calculating the count of how many dates are in each column when filters are selected.

Comment: Edit your question, add sample data in a table format (or easy to reproduced) and your desired output for certain filter

Comment: Refer to the documentation for  `CALCULATE ()`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax